# OpenCV Mat Single Cell

Tags: opencv, histogram, mat, gradient

I'm somewhat of a newbie when it comes to OpenCV. I've been sifting through Google search results for days to better understand mats but to no avail. Instead of rambling incoherently I'll just say what I'm looking to do. Basically, I want to create a table on top of an image solely as a way to reference certain image blocks. I then want to calculate intensity gradients of each cell. In other words, I want to be able to say, "Ok, what's the intensity gradient of C3?" I know it doesn't work like an Excel spreadsheet but what's the best way of going about this?

Here's what I have thus far. I haven't started on histograms obviously but this may serve as some help.

Thank you in advance for any insight.

```
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
//  Load and convert image to grayscale.
    Mat src;
    src = imread("/Users/Mikie/Documents/Xcode/Image Modify/images/HDimage.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
//  Initialize variables to store source size data.
    float h, w, nh;
    h = src.rows;
    w = src.cols;
    nh = (h/w)*640; // Maintain aspect ratio based on a desired width.

//  Ensure image loaded.
    if(src.empty()){
        printf(" No image data \n ");
        return -1;
    }
    // if(argc != 2 || !image.data)
    // {
    //    printf(" No image data \n ");
    //  return -1;
    // }

//  Create destination Mat.
    Mat dst(4, 4, CV_8UC1);

    resize(src, dst, Size(640, nh), CV_INTER_LINEAR); // Resize source while maintaing aspect ratio.
    //  Show results to verify size change. 
    imwrite("/Users/Mikie/Documents/Xcode/Image Modify/images/images/Gray_Image.jpg", dst);
    namedWindow("Gray image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Gray image", dst);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access mat elements directly.

```
//Create a matrix (filled with 0's) to hold the data
cv::Mat gradient = cv::Mat::zeros(originalImage.size(),CV_32F);

//Acces a certain element of the matrix
std::cout << gradient.at<float>(100,100) <<std::endl;
```

OpenCV also provides an option to define a ROI (Region of interest) for matrices. This might be usefull for your cell decomposition.

```
cv::Rect roi(originalImage.size().width * 0.5, originalImage.size().height, cellWidth, callHeight);
```

A more in depth example of this can be found in the following Q&A: [Using ROI in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946383/using-roi-in-opencv)

Finally, a gradient can be calculated using Sobel Derivatives of which opencv provides an excellent [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/sobel_derivatives/sobel_derivatives.html)